# Two Wireless Network for business

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid

I have an assignment where I have to set up two wireless networks for one business. One needs to be secured while the other public. I can set up a Wireless VLAN (SSID Employee and SSID Guest) and I could use access points. How would I draw a diagram of this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Tara! We *can* help you with your assignments, but we'd appreciate if you could show us what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck in the process. I'm sure you have some material to work with already?

Comment: I made a diagram of something that I thought would work.... Basically I had a modem and a wireless router that offered guest networks.  I said that we would set a SSID for employees and then turn on the guest account for guest usage.  I am not sure how to get the picture onto this site.

Comment: You can just paste me the link to the image in a comment and we'll upload it for you